# Extracting Values from Database into Array - Excel-VBA

Tags: arrays, database, vba, excel

I'm connected to an oracle database that basically outputs data into a sheet using an SQL statement I give it:

This is the code that copies it into a spreadsheet:

```
 Set oRsOracle = New ADODB.Recordset
    With oRsOracle
        .ActiveConnection = oConOracle
        .Open "SELECT CalcGrp_Name FROM Calc_Group"
        Sheets(2).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset oRsOracle
        .Close
    End With
    Set oRsOracle = Nothing

    oConOracle.Close
    Set oConOracle = Nothing
```

Basically instead of the line `Sheets(2).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset oRsOracle` is there a way to store these values into an Array or any data struct VB has to offer, I basically want to use these values and randomly populate them into another a data-test generation file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arrays or Variants for example:

```
Dim dat as Variant
dat = Array(record1, record2, record3)
```

---

In a loop you can set individual records:

```
For i = 1 to 10
  dat(i) = 'your record
next
```

---

In your code try this:

```
Dim dat as Variant

With oRsOracle
    .ActiveConnection = oConOracle
    .Open "SELECT CalcGrp_Name FROM Calc_Group"
    dat = oRsOracle.GetRows
    .Close
End With
```

---

To print results:

```
Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(dat) to UBound(dat)
  Debug.Print dat(i)
Next
```

Comment: So instead of `Sheets(2).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset oRsOracle` i should have a for loop with `dat(i).CopyFromRecordset oRsOracle` ?

Comment: Seem to be getting out range error's seems like its not adding it into data

Comment: `GetRows` returns a 2-D array, so it's `dat(field, row)`

Comment: So if I wanted to put in a cell would this work ? `Cells(1, "H").Value = dat(1, 1)` considering there is only one column ?

Comment: Flip it around: dat(1,1) = Cells(1, 10).value

Comment: @PortlandRunner Still getting subscript out of range :(

Answer (score 0):

Try something liki this

```
Dim Qdata as variant
Qdata= recordset.GetRows /// recordset is Adodb recordset
Qdata= Application.Transpose(Qdata)
```

End you have nice array